# symfony2 validation is disabled if by_reference is false / on true it works

Tags: validation, symfony, types, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms

I dont understand whats the problem with this "by_reference" option...

The problem is that the "form->isValid()" said "YES" but the emails collection issnt valid.
If i set the by_reference to true the form said "form->isValid()" is false.

But why it doesnt works wit by_reference => false??

My user form.

```
class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('emails', 'collection', array(
                'type' => new UserEmailType(),
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'by_reference' => false // if true it works!
            ))
        ;
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\User'
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'user';
    }
}
```

My user email form.

```
class UserEmailType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('email', 'email')
            ->add('comment', 'text', array('required' => false))
        ;
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\UserEmail'
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'useremail';
    }
}
```

The user entity.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="UserEmail", mappedBy="user", cascade={"all"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     * Following doesnt works :D
     * @Assert\Valid
     */
    private $emails;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->emails = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function addEmail(\Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\UserEmail $email)
    {
        $email->setUser($this);
        $this->emails[] = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeEmail(\Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\UserEmail $email)
    {
        $email->setUser();
        $this->emails->removeElement($email);
    }

    public function getEmails()
    {
        return $this->emails;
    }
}
```

And the user email entity.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="user_email", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="email_idx", columns={"email", "user"})})
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @UniqueEntity({"email", "user"})
 */
class UserEmail
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\Email(checkMX = false)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="comment", type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    private $comment;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="emails")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     * @Assert\NotNull()
     */
    private $user;

    /**
        ID
    */

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
        Email
    */

    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
        Comment
    */

    public function setComment($comment)
    {
        $this->comment = $comment;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getComment()
    {
        return $this->comment;
    }

    /**
        User
    */

    public function setUser(\Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\User $user = null)
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }
}
```

If I debug the form with `print_r($form->getErrorsAsString());die();` I got this.

```
ERROR: This value is not a valid email address.
emails:
    0:
        email:
            No errors
        comment:
            No errors
    1:
        email:
            No errors
        comment:
            No errors
```

I removed unused comments etc.
The database is already in sync with the current entity metadata.
And the assert annotation is imported.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: did you solve your problem my friend?

Comment: no. i created a new git branch and going a other way.

Comment: I guess the goal of your code is almost the same as mine. So, have a look on this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27560531/doctrine2-inverse-persistance-not-working-in-nested-forms/27567900#27567900